# Find IPv4 range from given subnet address and mask?

Tags: php, python, ip, mask, subnet

I have subnet address and mask, and I am looking for possible IP range in that subnet. Please let me know a solution in Python, PHP, or Java.

For example, I have the following details:

Subnet address: `10.113.12.40`

mask: `255.255.255.248`

Then what will be the IP Range?

Comment: Python has this library: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress which might be of interest to you

Comment: it doesn't seem like you tried something.. but as a starting point.. this php function http://php.net/ip2long turns an IPv4 address to a number.. from that point on I am guessing that it's a matter of subtracting/adding the right values

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 10.113. 12. 40 -> 00001010.01110001.00001100.00101000
255.255.255.248 -> 11111111.11111111.11111111.11111000
                                                   ^^^--- 3 bits for your network
```

2**3 = 8, so you've got 8 IPs in your network, giving you a range of `10.113.12.40` -> `10.113.12.47`

Basically a netmask defines what's "inside" and "outside" your network. Normal bitmask has `1` for outside, and `0` for inside. So a quicker version would be:

```
10.113.12.40 NOR 255.255.255.248 = 10.113.12.47
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---invert the mask and OR it with the network address.
```

Comment: Is it including broadcast and network IP, If so then I have 6 usable IPs is it right?

Comment: don't forget a gateway IP, if required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Marc B the genius!